# NSXMLParserDelegate parser:foundCDATA: returns rogue data

Tags: objective-c, nsxmlparser, cdata

This is truly baffling. I have an NSXMLParser reading a document that contains lots of CDATA sections. But I find that on some runs of the program, the data I receive in this method is wrong. It doesn't always happen, but when it does, there is usually around 100 characters of some other random section of the document after the part that it should have actually read.

Simplified, I have this:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock {
    NSString *queryFragment = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[CDATABlock bytes]];
    ....
}
```

Unbelievably, while reading the same section of the same document, sometimes the variable queryFragment gets exactly what I expect, but sometimes it has random junk on the end. I've ever seen it read past the end of the CDATA block and get raw XML!

I've been debugging this for two days now. Any ideas would be profoundly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is wrong because you expect a 0-terminated utf-8 string with `stringWithUTF8String:`

**the raw bytes arent 0 terminated though**

you have to use the data:

```
NSString *queryFragment = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Man, I can't believe I did that. Works perfectly now. Thank you so much!